# Identify Tasks/Process which are 7 days old in linux

Tags: linux, bash, process

How can I identify the processes running since 7 days in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
ps -eoetime,pid,user,cmd --sort -etime
```

You can select whatever information you want to display, see `man ps` for the long, long list. The above command lists all processes sorted in descending order by elapsed time. If you want to only display the processes which have been running at least seven days, you'll need to do something with `grep` or `awk`; in that case, you might just want to print out the `etime` and the `pid` since you can later on print out whatever data you want on the specific processes.

Unfortunately, the `etime` format is more designed for people than for scripts, but the following should work (although I haven't tested it):

```
ps -eoetime=,pid= | awk 'int(substr($1,1,index($1,"-"))) >= 7 { print }'
```

Brief explanation of command line options:

```
-e             show all processes
-eo...         same as -e -o...
-oetime=,pid=  for each process, print the elapsed time and pid.
               The '=' suppress the column headers
--sort -etime  sort the processes in descending order by elapsed time
               (+etime would have been ascending order)
```